# Shell script to check if user exist in remote server

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I have script to check remote servers if user exist, but it only checks the first user. The script reads a text file for server list and does SSH to each server and then checks if id exist:

```js
export users

for SERVER in `cat ./serverlist.txt`
do
        ssh $SERVER <<+
        set -A users "John" "Mary" "Joe" "Ana" "Jake" "Jana" "Ben" 
        for ids in {0..6}
        do
          id ${users[$ids]}
        done
+
done
```

Please help

Comment: Why set the variable on the remote at all?  Just do `for ids in John Mary ...`, or assign the variable locally and iterate through the local variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use `'+'` to prevent the local shell expands variables in the here document.

```
for SERVER in `cat ./serverlist.txt`
do
        ssh $SERVER <<'+'
        set -A users "John" "Mary" "Joe" "Ana" "Jake" "Jana" "Ben" 
        for ids in {0..6}
        do
          id ${users[$ids]}
        done
+
done
```

FYI.

```
for server in `cat ./serverlist.txt`
do
        ssh -- "$server" <<'+'
        set -A ids "John" "Mary" "Joe" "Ana" "Jake" "Jana" "Ben" 
        for id in "${ids[@]}"
        do
          id "$id"
        done
+
done
```